# Deltek CostPoint Formula to return just the year from a date

Tags: cognos

this seems like it should be simple, but i think i'm missing something...

see image below for context

i need a simple expression to return the year from a date from "DOB" which is /should be in a date format.

using CostPoint 8.0 (cognos analytics)

i'm sure i'm missing someting obvious, but i'm at a lost.. any takers?

[image]

Comment: The opening (after the function) and closing (after the qi) brackets are missing. The error message is complaining about parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is complaining about parsing. The opening (after the function) and closing (after the qi) brackets are missing. Reading error messages is usually the first thing you ought to do, as it might tell you what the query engine thinks is the problem, or give you sufficient hints to put you into the ballpark.

The information field will display the syntax of a function when you click on it.

You should also be aware of what functions are supported by whatever Database vendor you are using as it is preferable to use a native function, as that will mean that the probability of local processing will be reduced as it would be more likely to be pushed down to the data base for processing.

[image: reporting expression editor with arrow pointing out the functions tab]